# Azure - Create App Registration with replyUrlsWithType

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

We quite simply want to run a command to create an app registration within our Azure AD. It is a SPA and obviously we need to set a redirect URL to send users back to our app after they authenticate.

I tried

`az ad app create --display-name appName --reply-urls '[{\"url\":\"http://localhost:3000\",\"type\":\"Spa\"}]'`,

but this fails with

`Invalid value specified for property 'replyUrls' of resource 'Application'.`

Seems like this would be a very common operation to perform, but I can not locate docs on achieving this. [These](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_create) are the `az ad app create` docs.

Comment: Based on the documentation, `--reply-urls` should be space-separated URIs. In your case you're passing an object. I believe that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: @GauravMantri If I simply enter a string, the "type" defaults to "Web". I need "SPA" as the type

Comment: As per the comments here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14086, it seems this is not currently supported. It is recommended that you use `az rest`.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks! This is a very helpful resource. Disappointing such a simple use case is not supported with `az ad`. I'll look further into `az rest`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who comes across this, this is the solution I came up with after trying to accomplish this in several different ways (Thanks for the mentioning `az rest` Gaurav Mantri).

I created the following bash script

create-app-registration.sh

```
#Create App Registration
response=$(az ad app create --display-name $appName)

#Get the ObjectId of the newly created app registration
objectId=$(echo $response| cut -d'/' -f 3)

# Update app for SPA redirect
az rest --method PATCH --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/'$objectId \
    --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' \
    --body '{"spa":{"redirectUris":["'$redirectUri'"]}}'
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
Method Not Allowed({"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.","innerError":{"date":"2022-01-13T15:55:34","request-id":"fb5b2c11-8594-40c4-ac0e-84f996c57fc1","client-request-id":"fb5b2c11-8594-40c4-ac0e-84f996c57fc1"}}})

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @BryceBy. I did a quick test of your script and it worked well.

In my case, I need to get both app id and object id and create the scripts below.

```
clientid=$(az ad app create --display-name $appregname --query appId --output tsv)
objectid=$(az ad app show --id $clientid --query objectId --output tsv)
```